# Link annotation to Model Array

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

Basically I use a (model) array containing an array of places objects. For each place object I have various properties such as latitude, longitude, place name, place description etc.

I can place annotations where the places are. However when a user clicks on the right call out disclosure button I want them to segue to another view controller. Now I know how to do that.

The serious problem I am having is that I am unable to link the clicked annotation with my model array. In my next view controller I shall display all of the place info, but I can not discover which annotation has been clicked.

Think of a tableview which has index path.row, I need something similar to discover the right annotation.

Thanks.

```
    -(void)setMapAnnotations
{
    //Create the region - N.B - part of the map you wish to show
    MKCoordinateRegion dealMapRegion;

    //Center - N.B - The exact center of the region.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = 51.481623;
    center.longitude = -0.18519;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    dealMapRegion.center = center;
    dealMapRegion.span = span;

    [self.dealMapMapView setRegion:dealMapRegion animated:YES];

    //array to hold places
    NSMutableArray *placeLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;


    //After region has been set you need to populate the annotations
    for (DealListModel *dealLstObj in self.dealMapModelArray) {
        //Get the place from the model objects stored in the model array
        PlaceDealAnnotation *placeAnnontation = [[PlaceDealAnnotation alloc]init];
        double tempPlaceLatitude = [dealLstObj.placeLatitude doubleValue];
        double tempPlaceLongitude = [dealLstObj.placeLongitude doubleValue];

        location.latitude = tempPlaceLatitude;
        location.longitude = tempPlaceLongitude;
        placeAnnontation.coordinate = location;
        placeAnnontation.title = dealLstObj.placeDescription;
        //adding array of locations map
        [placeLocations addObject:placeAnnontation];
    }

    [self.dealMapMapView addAnnotations:placeLocations];

}//end of setMapAnnotations


-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"CustomViewAnnontation";

    DealMapCustomAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = (DealMapCustomAnnotationView *) [self.dealMapMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    if (!customAnnotationView) {
        customAnnotationView = [[DealMapCustomAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotationwithImage:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier annotationViewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]];

        customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }

    return customAnnotationView;

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapPlaceSegue" sender:view];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solutions to associate annotation whit Model Array.

The below solution is what i uesd:

1.add int variable "tag" in your PlaceDealAnnotation

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int tag;
```

2.change the "for cycle" in setMapAnnotations: method

```
//After region has been set you need to populate the annotations
for (int tag = 0; tag < [self.dealMapModelArray count]; tag++) {
    //Get the place from the model objects stored in the model array
    DealListModel *dealLstObj = [self.dealMapModelArray objectAtIndex:tag];
    PlaceDealAnnotation *placeAnnontation = [[PlaceDealAnnotation alloc]init];
    double tempPlaceLatitude = [dealLstObj.placeLatitude doubleValue];
    double tempPlaceLongitude = [dealLstObj.placeLongitude doubleValue];
    //set tag here
    placeAnnontation.tag = tag;
    location.latitude = tempPlaceLatitude;
    location.longitude = tempPlaceLongitude;
    placeAnnontation.coordinate = location;
    placeAnnontation.title = dealLstObj.placeDescription;
    //adding array of locations map
    [placeLocations addObject:placeAnnontation];
}
```

3.implement the following mapView's delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
     PlaceDealAnnotation * annotation = [view annotation];
     int tag = annotation.tag;
     //get the model your want here
     DealListModel *targetModel = [self.dealMapModelArray objectAtIndex:tag];
     //go to the next view controller here
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly. That was so helpful. I did look for a tag property on MKAnnotation but came up with nothing. It didn't occur to me to create my own. No doubt this solution will be useful for this and other things in the future! Thanks